# Approximating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B := A + E$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I have a matrix $B := A + E$, where $A$ is diagonal and $E$ is an off-diagonal, symmetric matrix whose non-diagonal elements are small. Is there any way to obtain the approximate eigenvalue and eigenvector of $B$?

I came across this approximation

$$\lambda_B = \lambda_A + \frac{x^t E x}{x^t x}$$

where $x$ is the eigenvector of $A$. However, this does not work for me, because, $A$ is diagonal, and diagonal elements of $E = 0$. In this case, I get $x^t E x = 0$. Is there any other method?

Also assume the eigenvalues of $\lambda_A$ is positive, if it helps.

Comment: Eigenvalue? Singular?

Comment: Off-diagonal matrix means here a matrix with zero-diagonal.

Comment: Edited the question in which I added that E is symmetric. Assume the diagonal entries of A is positive, if it helps.

Comment: The eigenvalues should not depend on $x$.

Comment: I would rewrite $ A:= D+E$ where $D$ is diagonal.

Comment: @Angela Look at something called pseudospectrum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudospectrum Check also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452987